# Is there a way to clean up the information written in a socket stream?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm using SSL sockets to exchange messages with a server. After writing the message and flushing the stream, I'm manually clearing the byte array holding the message. However, if I obtain a memory dump, I can still see the message. Is there a way to make sure that the memory hold by the stream is cleaned up after writing on it?

Comment: Without seeing your code we have no way of knowing all the places those bytes may be copied or what your memory dump shows. Perhaps those bytes were first in a String, or somewhere else.